# How to start ChromeDriver in headless mode

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to try out headless chrome, but I am running into this issue, that I can't start the driver in headless mode. I was following [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome). am I missing something ? The code execution gets  stuck in `var browser = new ChromeDriver();` line

Here is my code:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions
{
    BinaryLocation = @"C:\Users\2-as Aukstas\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ChromeTest\ChromeTest\bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe",
    DebuggerAddress = "localhost:9222"
};

chromeOptions.AddArguments(new List<string>() {"headless", "disable-gpu" });

var browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);


browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
Console.WriteLine(browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#h-top-questions")).Text);
```

Comment: What's your `chromedriver.exe` version?

Comment: My version is 2.30.0. Got it from NuGet

Comment: `BinaryLocation` should point to the `exe` of Chrome (the browser), not `chromedriver.exe`

Comment: Yes you are right. But still doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Chrome version 60 is out so all you need to do is to download ChromeDriver and Selenium via NuGet and use this simple code and everything works like a charm. Amazing.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

...



var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");

using (var browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions))
{
  // add your code here
}
```

**DATED**

There is a solution until the official release of Chrome 60. You can download Chrome Canary and use headless with it. After installation set `BinaryLocation` to point to Chrome Canary. Also comment out the `DebuggerAddress` line (it forces Chrome to time out):

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions
{
    BinaryLocation = @"C:\Users\2-as Aukstas\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe",
    //DebuggerAddress = "127.0.0.1:9222"
};

chromeOptions.AddArguments(new List<string>() { "no-sandbox", "headless", "disable-gpu" });

var _driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Which nuget package is necessary for Chromedriver, there are a few - `Chromium.ChromeDriver`, `WebDriverChromeDriver`, `Selenium.Webdriver.ChromeDriver` etc

Comment: Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver

Comment: Why use new List<string>?
just use
`options.AddArguments("headless");`

Comment: Yes that is correct. The other arguments were needed before the update

Comment: FYI the namespace for the WebDriver dll is OpenQA (this was not apparent to me), so you would add "using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;" to the top of your code file.

Comment: Yeah you are right. you need to include OpenQA.Selenium and OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome. Gonna edit my post

Answer (score 6):

For you that did not get reference for ChromeDriver. 
Use this step :

1. Download the dll from this: http://seleniumtestings.com/selenium-download/
2. Extract, and you should see: Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.dll, ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core.dll, WebDriver.dll and WebDriver.Support.dll
3. Add those files via "Add Reference"

Now you can use it:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments(new List<string>() {
    "--silent-launch",
    "--no-startup-window",
    "no-sandbox",
    "headless",});

var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;    // This is to hidden the console.
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

====

If after you run, you are still facing error about no ChromeDriver.exe file, try to add the Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver, WebDriver.ChromeDriver, WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32, Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver via nuget.

Comment: The provided link is broken.

Comment: Please go to my other alternative below.

Answer (score 4):

As alternative:

- Add 2 libraries via NuGet like below picture.
- Try below Code:

  ```
  String url = "http://www.google.com";
  var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  chromeOptions.AddArguments(new List<string>() { "headless" });

  var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
  ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
  ```

[image: Selenium Chrome WebDriver]

Answer (score 2):

I see on https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome that headless won't be available on Windows until Chrome 60.

Comment: Windows 10. That answers that... :(

Answer (score 1):

Below i have given how to set the headless to true for firefox and chrome browsers.

```
FirefoxOptions ffopt = new FirefoxOptions();
FirefoxOptions option = ffopt.setHeadless(true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(option);


ChromeOptions coptions = new ChromeOptions();
ChromeOptions options = coptions.setHeadless(true);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: It looks like this code is in Java. The question was for C#. There is no `setHeadless()` method (or equivalent) in C#'s `ChromeDriver` class.