# stats.nba.com (angular) does not give the DOM completely in selenium headless mode

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

full path i need:

`html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/nba-stat-table[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tfoot`

headless path that i can get:

`html/body/main/div[2]/div/div`

HtmlAgilityPack and PuppeteerSharp (both .NET nuget packages) also do not work.

Are there any approaches to **scrape** such sites sparingly?

Comment: Relevant HTML? Code trials? Errors encountered?

Comment: @DebanjanB  NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I used a faster [site](https://www.foxsports.com/nba/boxscore?id=33748)  with the same statistics
2. I used answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51457307/how-to-make-asynchronous-calls-using-htmlagilitypack) SO  question (2nd option [puppeteer-sharp](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp))