# C# selenium script fails to run in Chrome headless mode however same script runs fine in Firefox headless mode

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, headless

This is my script:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Chromedriver version: 88.0.4324.9600
Chrome version: 89.0.4389.114

I get the below error

```
 Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
      (Session info: headless chrome=89.0.4389.114)
  Stack Trace: 
    RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
    RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
    RemoteNavigator.GoToUrl(String url)
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130993/how-to-start-chromedriver-in-headless-mode) thread however it didn't help. As mentioned my Chrome version is 89 which is above 60. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Chromedriver because:

- Chromedriver version 88 Supports Chrome version 88
- ChromeDriver version 89 Supports Chrome version 89

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: Thanks @Lia for your reply. Unfortunately the Chrome fails to work in headless mode even after updating Chromedriver & Chrome version. Currently my configuration is,

 Chrome version: 90.0.4430.72
Chromedriver version: 90.0.4430.2400